# Row_Number with complex conditions

Tags: sql-server-2005, row-number

Is it possible to use `Row_Number()` to number rows on something else than a simple partition done with `Group By` ?

This is my particular case :

```
Id    Type    Date
--    ----    ----
 1      16    Some Date
 2      16    Some Date   
 3      16    Some Date
 4      32    Some Date
 5      64    Some Date
 6      64    Some Date
 7     128    Some Date
 8     256    Some Date
 9     256    Some Date
10     256    Some Date
```

I want to partition the numbering in the following way (row numbering is sorted by date) :

```
Id    Type    RowNb
--    ----    -----
 6      64        1
 4      32        2
 5      64        3
 9     256        1
 3      16        2
 1      16        3
 8     256        4
 7     128        5
 2      16        6
10     256        7
```

ie: **Every other type than 32 and 64 are numbered together**. The numbering of types 32 and 64 is optional because I only need to sort the others one.

What I really want to do, is retrieve **all the rows with type 32 and 64 and only the row with the lowest date from the other type**. The reason why I'm asking this specific question is that in the future it is possible that I will have to retrieve more than just the first column and I think it will be easier if I can number my rows like that. If you have another solution, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course you can have complex partitioning expressions, just like you could have complex grouping expressions. Here's one possible way how you could rank rows in your example:

```
SELECT
  Id,
  Type,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    PARTITION BY CASE WHEN Type IN (32, 64) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
    Order BY Date
  )
FROM atable
```

But you'd have to repeat that condition later when filtering rows to display. So, if I were you, I might try something like this:

```
WITH marked AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    TypeGroup = CASE WHEN Type IN (32, 64) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
  FROM atable
),
ranked AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    RowNb = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TypeGroup ORDER BY Date)
  FROM
)
SELECT
  Id,
  Type,
  RowNb
FROM ranked
WHERE TypeGroup = 1 OR RowNb = 1
ORDER BY TypeGroup, RowNb
```

Comment: Thank you, the first solution works like a charm for me, and like you said the second one can also be useful in some case.